# Minecraft META-INF File

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been watching videos about installing mods and Optifine on Minecraft. Out of all the videos I've watched, they always delete the META-INF File. I know what happens if you don't delete it but what if I want to add another mod into my Minecraft? What will I have to do if the file has been already deleted? Do I just install the mod and put together the mod files with Minecraft using WinRAR when I don't have the file anymore? Or will there always be a META-INF file to delete each time I install a mod?

If you dont understand what I just said heres what I'm basically saying. How do I install another mod when I've already deleted the META-INF file when there is nothing to delete. Will there be another META-INF file to delete again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file won't regenerate unless you update Minecraft, and needs to be removed only once for a given version. (If Minecraft has an update and you pick "yes" when it asks if you want to update, it'll reinstall a fresh, new copy of the game, with a brand-new META-INF file and none of your mods.)

The META-INF file is a code signing file. Removing it is necessary if you mod Minecraft because the game will no longer match the code signature, and therefore won't start. Removing it prevents the game from checking if it matches, so then it runs fine.

Comment: I've had to remove it more than once - would this be from an update?

Comment: @AliceRees Yep. Updates reset Minecraft to its "stock" state, erasing all mods and replacing the META-INF file.

Comment: Cheers for clearing that up for me :)

Comment: @AliceRees Thanks for the question; it helped clarify the answer!